# Auto Login to web page using Prowser in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to simulate an auto login behaviour to a website and scrap the HTML after logging in by using [Prowser](http://prowser.sourceforge.net/#whatisprowser) library in Java.

Code fragment:

```
<br>
Prowser prowser = new Prowser();<br>
Tab tab = prowser.createTab();<br>
Request request;<br>
String html ="";<br>
try {<br>
    request = new Request("http://username:password@www.gmail.com");<br>
    Response response = tab.go(request);<br>
    html = response.getPageSource();<br>
} catch (Exception e) {<br>
    e.printStackTrace();<br>
}<br>
System.out.println(html);<br>
```

With this code I am able to login and scrap out the HTML if my username doesn't contains ***@***. But if username is an emailId then this doesn't works and returns null.

Any suggestions how to use this library when my username has ***@*** in it. Or any other library suitable for what I am trying to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cal URL-encode it using %40 (which is @). The server should be able to decode it properly, but of course... it depends on the server implementation.

Comment: And the Java code for that would be `URLEncoder.encode(username)`

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your suggestion. 'sphreg.asiaone.com/RegAuth2/enLogin.html' this is the page I am trying to log into, but after encoding also it didn't worked.

Comment: Did you encode just the username or did you encode the whole URL string? The code I suggested would be `request = new Request("http://" + URLEncoder.encode("username") +  ":password@www.gmail.com");`

Comment: Yes, did the same way. But it just takes me to login page, but not logs in. And same fro scrapped HTML, it gives me HTML for login page.

Comment: Well, all that a browser (and Prowser) does is to take the user name and password and Base64 encode it in an "Authorization" header. So one thing you can try is to add an "Authorization" header to your request with the value `"Basic " + Base64.encode("username:password")`

Comment: byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("mudit02@gmail.com".getBytes());
   String url = "http://"+new String(encodedBytes)+":password@sphreg.asiaone.com/RegAuth2/enLogin.html"; I tried with this but still the same. It only goes to login page but doesn't logs in.